# How to Minimize variable names but keep line breaks on Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, lambda, bundle

I am looking a way to minimize the variables and stuff but keep line breaks so the codes are more debugable in my production envirenmnet.

Setting minimize: false will keep original file names. I am working with some Lamda function. So reducing size was expected to increase the invocation time of my fucntions.
Adding source maps is expensive on the bundle size. If I could preserve line breaks and introduce a cheap source map, I hope it will reduce overall build size.

**
I am using extend to use a base cofig. The attched one is the base config I currently use.**

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {

  target: 'node',
  mode: 'production',
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
  },

  entry: handlers.reduce(function (obj, el) {
    obj[(path.parse(el).dir+"/"+path.parse(el).name).replace( /^(.\/)?[^/]+\//,"")] = el;
    return obj;
  }, {}),

  output: {
    path: output_dir,
    filename: "[name].js",
    clean: true,

  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,

        use: [
          {
            loader: 'ts-loader',
            options: {
              transpileOnly: true,
            },
          },
        ],
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
  optimization: {
    minimize: false,
    splitChunks: {
      chunks: 'all', // Split and share code among entries
    },
  },

};
```

I tried full source-maps and minimize disable so far, Any other suggetions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use an external minifier (like Terser plugin which is already included in webpack module) as core webpack minifier is not configurable.

See [webpack doc](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/terser-webpack-plugin/) for terser plugin config.

With Terser, you can achieve keeping line breaks in two ways :

- Use `beautify` format option but it seems deprecated
- Use `semicolons` format option as it tends to use line breaks instead of semi-colons for line ends in minified output

Here's an excerpt of a possible webpack configuration :

```js
optimization: {
    minimize: true,
    minimizer: [
        new TerserPlugin({
            terserOptions: {
                format: {
                    semicolons : false
                }
            }
        })
    ]
}
```

Link to [Full terser API](https://terser.org/docs/api-reference/#format-options) for fine tuning.